# How to use disabled property in child component and how to pass function dynamically?

Tags: angular, typescript

I do have an extra component for a button to be used/embedded in different other components which contain a form.

In other words the button is alway the same, has the same style formatting etc. The only thing which is different, are some function(s) which should be invoked when clicking the button depending on the porcess.

For instance in **user-login.html** I would invoke: **`(click)="login(inputUserName.value, inputUserPass.value)"`** but in **`user-register.html`**, I would invoke: **`(click)="register(inputUserEmail.value)"`**

When trying to implement this concept:

**button-form.component.html:**

```
<button mat-raised-button [disabled]="!form.valid" [color]="'primary'">
    <span>{{buttonText}}</span>
</button>
```

**`button-form.component.ts`:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-button-form',
  templateUrl: './button-form.component.html'
})
export class ButtonFormComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() buttonText: string;
    constructor() { }
    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

**user-login.html:**

```
<form #form="ngForm">
   ....
    <app-form-button [buttonText]="TextToShowOnButton"></app-form-button>
   ....
</form>
```

I face two issues:

1. Regarding the **`disabled`** property I get **`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined`**. This error makes sense as the property `form` isn't defined in **`button-form.component.ts`**, but the form exists in **`login.html`** as **`<form #form="ngForm">`** . I tried it using interpolation inside property binding, but it didn't help or I didn't use it correctly.
2. I can't manage how pass the function dynamically to the Button 
   depending on the form and the process.

I have been searching, but couldn't really find a solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to pass the form to the button, as the button is an isolated component and shoud not know anything about its surroundings. Anything regarding the button's behaviour should be passed via its `inputs`:

So:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-button-form',
  templateUrl: './button-form.component.html'
})
export class ButtonFormComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() buttonText: string;
    @Input() form: NgForm;
    @Output() click: EventEmitter<Event> = new EventEmitter();
    constructor() { }
    ngOnInit() {
    }

    onClick(event: Event): void {
        this.click.emit(event);
    }
}
```

Now, in the template:

```
<button mat-raised-button [disabled]="!form.valid" [color]="'primary'" (click)="onClick($event)">
    <span>{{buttonText}}</span>
</button>
```

And, in the form where you want to use it:

```
<form #form="ngForm">
   ....
    <app-form-button [form]="form" [buttonText]="TextToShowOnButton" (click)="register(...)"></app-form-button>
   ....
</form>
```

Basically, you add a new input for the form, and an `@Output` to pass the button's `click` event up.

Hope this serves you.

Answer (score 1):

You could modify your `button-form.component` to accept another input property `@Input() isValid: boolean`, pass that it from your parent component with `<app-form-button [isValid]="form.valid" [buttonText]="TextToShowOnButton"></app-form-button>` and then use it in your HTML

```
<button mat-raised-button [disabled]="!isValid" [color]="'primary'">
    <span>{{buttonText}}</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I can't manage how pass the function dynamically to the Button
>   depending on the form and the process.

You shouldn't pass a function although you can. you should use an Output event emitter and register it in the hoster component.

```
<form #form="ngForm">
   ....
    <app-form-button (onSomething)="foo($event)"...></app-form-button>
   ....
</form>
```

Comment: Just one question why are you go against Ouput event ?

Comment: I've written _you should use an Output event emitter_ . Why do you think i'm against it ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: It's not me who's asking in regards to `Ouput event`

Comment: @Royi Namir i merged your sentences sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it in this way:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-button-form',
  templateUrl: './button-form.component.html'
})
export class ButtonFormComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() buttonText: string;
    @Input() disabled: boolean;
    @Output() buttonClicked: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    constructor() { }
    ngOnInit() {
    }
}

<form #form="ngForm">
   ....
    <app-form-button [buttonText]="TextToShowOnButton" [disabled]="!form.valid" 
(buttonClicked)="myFunction"></app-form-button>
```

In this way not only you will be able to easily achieve that, but also made the button component completely independent by abstracting it away (As making the button component verify the form value by itself will have restrcited it's use only in places of form, same goes for the click event)